# How to use www root level web.Config file with "Use Visual Studio Development Center"

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I hope I can explain this question sufficiently...

In the past, we have utilized a web.Config file in the wwwroot folder so multiple sites can pick up the same connectionstrings/app settings (it also allows us to have different connectionstrings on different servers, so we could publish the project without having to make changes to its web.config every time).

I'm trying to do that with Visual Studio 2010.  I have a Web Project, and under Properties - Web tab, I have "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and a Virtual Path.  Since it's not running under IIS, it won't pick up a config file stored in c:\inetpub\wwwroot (makes sense).  Is there a way to get it to pick up such a file in this situation?